# How to apply sorting and then pagination at server side in node.js on a mongo database

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, sorting

Is there any way for applying sorting and pagination at sever side.
If sort and then paginate, its useless considering the load on server will be same. It will fetch- sort whole db,then display page, then on next page again fetch-sort whole db and display page-2.
If i paginate first then it will sort only the selected paginated records(like in groups of 10).

The code shown below paginates by input querying page & size and then sorts with column & name. It only sorts the paginated records

```
const Course = require('../models/courseModel');
const Country = require('../models/countryModel');
const Class = require('../models/classModel');
const StudyCenter = require('../models/studyCenterModel');
const CourseType = require('../models/course_typeModel');
const CourseCategory = require('../models/course_categoryModel');

const getPagination = (page, size) => {
  var limit = 10;
  if (size === "all") limit = 100000;   //all is only good if total courses in db are less than 100000
  else limit = size ? +size : 10;
  const offset = page ? (page - 1) * limit : 0;

  return { limit, offset };
};
exports.getCourses = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { page, size, keyword, order, column } = req.query;
    const { limit, offset } = getPagination(page, size);

    var condition1 = keyword ? { name: { $regex: new RegExp(keyword), $options: "i" } } : {};
    var condition2 = keyword ? { code: { $regex: new RegExp(keyword), $options: "i" } } : {};



    const courses = await Course.paginate(
      {
        $and: [
          { deleted_at: null },
          {
            $or: [
              condition1, // Check if condition1 is met (name match)
              condition2, // Check if condition2 is met (code match)
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      { offset, limit }
    )

    columnName = column ? column : 'name';
    // Sorting the paginated data using JavaScript after fetching
    courses.docs.sort((a, b) => {
      // Assuming columnName is the field name you want to sort by
      const fieldA = a[columnName];
      const fieldB = b[columnName];

      if (order === 'desc') {
        if (fieldA > fieldB) return -1;
        if (fieldA < fieldB) return 1;
        return 0;
      } else {
        if (fieldA < fieldB) return -1;
        if (fieldA > fieldB) return 1;
        return 0;
      }
    });
res.status(200).json({
      status: 'success',
      totalItems: courses.totalDocs,
      data: courses.docs,
      totalPages: courses.totalPages,
      currentPage: courses.page,
      message: 'All courses fetched successfully'
    });
```

i tried to do some changes below

```
let sortOptions = {};

// Check if order query string is passed and set sorting options accordingly
if (order === 'asc' || order === 'desc') {
  sortOptions[name] = order === 'asc' ? 1 : -1;
}

// Fetch all data from the database and sort it based on the provided criteria
const sortedCourses = await Course.find({
  $and: [
    { deleted_at: null },
    {
      $or: [
        condition1, // Check if condition1 is met (name match)
        condition2, // Check if condition2 is met (code match)
      ],
    },
  ],
}).sort(sortOptions);

// Apply pagination to the sorted data
const startIndex = offset;
const endIndex = offset + limit;
const paginatedCourses = sortedCourses.slice(startIndex, endIndex);

// paginatedCourses contains the requested slice of sorted data
```

here whenever I hit the url or shift pages whole record is being fetched which defeats the purpose of pagination.
Ideally I would like to fetch-sort the data once and then dislay the sorted results page by page

Comment: "Ideally I would like to fetch-sort the data once and then dislay the sorted results page by page" - Isn't this what a cursor is for?